# How to see which ANSI code page is used in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, locale, codepages

How can I get the number of ANSI code page that define in my Windows?

I serach a simply way , via command line  is the best, but via c/c# is pretty good (python is the worst way)

I looking so much and dind't find any simple way

Comment: Do you mean `chcp`? Or something else?

Comment: The ACP is a changeable attribute of each thread. You must be asking how it gets initialized from more permanent configurations. It would depend on the program and/or programming environment. Which sort of begs the question: why do you need to determine this programmatically when the programming environment has already done so? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Via **command line**:

Check system-wide ANSI codepage:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" -v ACP|find /I "ACP"
```

> ```
> ACP    REG_SZ    1250
> ```

Check system-wide ANSI, OEM and MAC codepages:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" | findstr /I "CP.*REG_SZ"
```

> ```
> ACP    REG_SZ    1250
> OEMCP    REG_SZ    852
> MACCP    REG_SZ    10029
> ```

**Note**: above results (`1250`/`852`/`10029`) are valid for **my** current [Windows *language settings*](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-10/change-system-language-windows-10/).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the number of ANSI code page that define in my Windows?
>
> I serach a simply way , via command line is the best, but via c/c# is
>   pretty good (python is the worst way)

Sample In C++  for all Code Pages =>

(you can add a filter on "ANSI" )

```cpp
    OutputDebugString(L"Installed Code Pages :\n");
    EnumSystemCodePages((CODEPAGE_ENUMPROC)EnumCodePagesProc, CP_INSTALLED);
    OutputDebugString(L"Supported Code Pages :\n");
    EnumSystemCodePages((CODEPAGE_ENUMPROC)EnumCodePagesProc, CP_SUPPORTED);
```

```cpp
    BOOL CALLBACK EnumCodePagesProc(LPTSTR lpCodePageString)
    {
        CPINFOEX cpiex = { 0 };
        if (GetCPInfoEx((UINT)_wtoi(lpCodePageString), 0, &cpiex))
        {
            WCHAR wsBuffer[MAX_PATH];
            wsprintf(wsBuffer, L"\tCode Page : %s\n", cpiex.CodePageName);
            OutputDebugString(wsBuffer);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

I get on my OS (Windows 10) =>

```
Installed Code Pages :
    Code Page : 10000 (MAC - romain)
    Code Page : 10001 (MAC - japonais)
    Code Page : 10002 (MAC - chinois traditionnel Big5)
    Code Page : 10003 (MAC - coréen)
    Code Page : 10004 (MAC - arabe)
    Code Page : 10005 (MAC - hébreu)
    Code Page : 10006 (MAC - grec I)
    Code Page : 10007 (MAC - cyrillique)
    Code Page : 10008 (MAC - chinois simplifié GB 2312)
    Code Page : 10010 (MAC - Roumanie)
    Code Page : 10017 (MAC - Ukraine)
    Code Page : 10021 (MAC - thaï)
    Code Page : 10029 (MAC - latin II)
    Code Page : 10079 (MAC - islandais)
    Code Page : 10081 (MAC - turc)
    Code Page : 10082 (MAC - croate)
    Code Page : 1026 (IBM EBCDIC - Turc (Latin-5))
    Code Page : 1047 (IBM EBCDIC - Latin-1/système ouvert)
    Code Page : 1140  (IBM EBCDIC - É.U./Canada (37 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1141  (IBM EBCDIC - Allemagne (20273 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1142  (IBM EBCDIC - Danemark/Norvège (20277 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1143  (IBM EBCDIC - Finlande/Suède (20278 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1144 (IBM EBCDIC - Italie (20280 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1145  (IBM EBCDIC - Amérique Latine/Espagne (20284 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1146 (IBM EBCDIC - Royaume-Uni (20285 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1148 (IBM EBCDIC - International (500 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1149  (IBM EBCDIC - Islandais (20871 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1250  (ANSI - Europe centrale)
    Code Page : 1251  (ANSI - cyrillique)
    Code Page : 1252  (ANSI - latin I)
    Code Page : 1253  (ANSI - grec)
    Code Page : 1254  (ANSI - turc)
    Code Page : 1255  (ANSI - hébreu)
    Code Page : 1256  (ANSI - arabe)
    Code Page : 1257  (ANSI - baltique)
    Code Page : 1258  (ANSI/OEM - Vietnam)
    Code Page : 1361  (coréen - Johab)
    Code Page : 20000 (CNS - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20001 (TCA - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20002 (Eten - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20003 (IBM5550 - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20004 (TeleText - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20005 (Wang - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20105 (IA5 IRV alphabet international No.5)
    Code Page : 20106 (IA5 allemand)
    Code Page : 20107 (IA5 suédois)
    Code Page : 20108 (IA5 norvégien)
    Code Page : 20127 (ASCII - É-U.)
    Code Page : 20261 (T.61)
    Code Page : 20269 (ISO 6937 accent sans espace)
    Code Page : 20273 (IBM EBCDIC - Allemagne)
    Code Page : 20277 (IBM EBCDIC - Danemark/Norvège)
    Code Page : 20278 (IBM EBCDIC - Finlande/Suède)
    Code Page : 20280 (IBM EBCDIC - Italie)
    Code Page : 20284 (IBM EBCDIC - Amérique latine/Espagne)
    Code Page : 20285 (IBM EBCDIC - Royaume Uni)
    Code Page : 20290 (IBM EBCDIC - japonais Katakana étendu)
    Code Page : 20297 (IBM EBCDIC - France)
    Code Page : 20420 (IBM EBCDIC - arabe)
    Code Page : 20423 (IBM EBCDIC - grec)
    Code Page : 20424 (IBM EBCDIC - hébreu)
    Code Page : 20833 (IBM EBCDIC - coréen étendu)
    Code Page : 20838 (IBM EBCDIC - thaï)
    Code Page : 20866 (russe - KOI8)
    Code Page : 20871 (IBM EBCDIC - islandais)
    Code Page : 20880 (IBM EBCDIC - cyrillique (russe))
    Code Page : 20905 (IBM EBCDIC - turc)
    Code Page : 20924 (IBM EBCDIC - Latin-1/Système ouvert (1047 + Euro))
    Code Page : 20932 (JIS X 0208-1990  0212-1990)
    Code Page : 20936 (chinois simplifié GB2312)
    Code Page : 21025 (IBM EBCDIC - cyrillique (serbe, bulgare))
    Code Page : 21027 (minuscules alpha étendues)
    Code Page : 21866 (ukrainien - KOI8-U)
    Code Page : 28591 (ISO 8859-1 latin I)
    Code Page : 28592 (ISO 8859-2 Europe centrale)
    Code Page : 28593 (ISO 8859-3 latin 3)
    Code Page : 28594 (ISO 8859-4 baltique)
    Code Page : 28595 (ISO 8859-5 cyrillique)
    Code Page : 28596 (ISO 8859-6 arabe)
    Code Page : 28597 (ISO 8859-7 grec)
    Code Page : 28598 (ISO 8859-8 hébreu : ordre visuel)
    Code Page : 28599 (ISO 8859-9 latin 5)
    Code Page : 28603 (ISO 8859-13 Latin 7)
    Code Page : 28605 (ISO 8859-15 latin 9)
    Code Page : 37    (IBM EBCDIC - États-Unis/Canada)
    Code Page : 38598 (ISO 8859-8 hébreu : tri logique)
    Code Page : 437   (OEM - États-Unis)
    Code Page : 500   (IBM EBCDIC - international)
    Code Page : 50220 (ISO-2022 japonais sans Katakana demi largeur)
    Code Page : 50220 (ISO-2022 japonais avec Katakana demi largeur)
    Code Page : 50222 (ISO-2022 japonais JIS X 0201-1989)
    Code Page : 50225 (ISO-2022 coréen)
    Code Page : 50227 (ISO-2022 chinois simplifié)
    Code Page : 50229 (ISO-2022 chinois traditionnel)
    Code Page : 51949 (EUC-coréen)
    Code Page : 52936 (HZ-GB2312 chinois simplifié)
    Code Page : 54936 (chinois simplifié GB 18030)
    Code Page : 55000 (7 bits SMS GSM)
    Code Page : 55001 (espagnol 7 bits SMS GSM)
    Code Page : 55002 (portugais 7 bits SMS GSM)
    Code Page : 55003 (turc 7 bits SMS GSM)
    Code Page : 55004 (grec 7 bits SMS GSM)
    Code Page : 57002 (ISCII - dévanâgari)
    Code Page : 57003 (ISCII - bengali)
    Code Page : 57004 (ISCII - tamoul)
    Code Page : 57005 (ISCII - télougou)
    Code Page : 57006 (ISCII - assamais)
    Code Page : 57007 (ISCII - odia (oriya))
    Code Page : 57008 (ISCII - kannada)
    Code Page : 57009 (ISCII - malayalam)
    Code Page : 57010 (ISCII - gujarati)
    Code Page : 57011 (ISCII - pendjabi (gurmukhi))
    Code Page : 708   (arabe - ASMO)
    Code Page : 720   (arabe - ASMO transparent)
    Code Page : 737   (OEM - grec 437G)
    Code Page : 775   (OEM - baltique)
    Code Page : 850   (OEM - latin multilingue I)
    Code Page : 852   (OEM - latin II)
    Code Page : 855   (OEM - cyrillique)
    Code Page : 857   (OEM - turc)
    Code Page : 858   (OEM - latin multilingue I + Euro)
    Code Page : 860   (OEM - portugais)
    Code Page : 861   (OEM - islandais)
    Code Page : 862   (OEM - hébreu)
    Code Page : 863   (OEM - canadien français)
    Code Page : 864   (OEM - arabe)
    Code Page : 865   (OEM - nordique)
    Code Page : 866   (OEM - russe)
    Code Page : 869   (OEM - grec moderne)
    Code Page : 870   (IBM EBCDIC - multilingue/ROECE (latin-2))
    Code Page : 874   (ANSI/OEM - thaï)
    Code Page : 875   (IBM EBCDIC - grec moderne)
    Code Page : 932   (ANSI/OEM - japonais décalage JIS)
    Code Page : 936   (ANSI/OEM - chinois simplifié GBK)
    Code Page : 949   (ANSI/OEM - coréen)
    Code Page : 950   (ANSI/OEM - chinois traditionnel Big5)
    Code Page : 65000 (UTF-7)
    Code Page : 65001 (UTF-8)
Supported Code Pages :
    Code Page : 10000 (MAC - romain)
    Code Page : 10001 (MAC - japonais)
    Code Page : 10002 (MAC - chinois traditionnel Big5)
    Code Page : 10003 (MAC - coréen)
    Code Page : 10004 (MAC - arabe)
    Code Page : 10005 (MAC - hébreu)
    Code Page : 10006 (MAC - grec I)
    Code Page : 10007 (MAC - cyrillique)
    Code Page : 10008 (MAC - chinois simplifié GB 2312)
    Code Page : 10010 (MAC - Roumanie)
    Code Page : 10017 (MAC - Ukraine)
    Code Page : 10021 (MAC - thaï)
    Code Page : 10029 (MAC - latin II)
    Code Page : 10079 (MAC - islandais)
    Code Page : 10081 (MAC - turc)
    Code Page : 10082 (MAC - croate)
    Code Page : 1026 (IBM EBCDIC - Turc (Latin-5))
    Code Page : 1047 (IBM EBCDIC - Latin-1/système ouvert)
    Code Page : 1140  (IBM EBCDIC - É.U./Canada (37 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1141  (IBM EBCDIC - Allemagne (20273 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1142  (IBM EBCDIC - Danemark/Norvège (20277 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1143  (IBM EBCDIC - Finlande/Suède (20278 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1144 (IBM EBCDIC - Italie (20280 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1145  (IBM EBCDIC - Amérique Latine/Espagne (20284 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1146 (IBM EBCDIC - Royaume-Uni (20285 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1148 (IBM EBCDIC - International (500 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1149  (IBM EBCDIC - Islandais (20871 + Euro))
    Code Page : 1250  (ANSI - Europe centrale)
    Code Page : 1251  (ANSI - cyrillique)
    Code Page : 1252  (ANSI - latin I)
    Code Page : 1253  (ANSI - grec)
    Code Page : 1254  (ANSI - turc)
    Code Page : 1255  (ANSI - hébreu)
    Code Page : 1256  (ANSI - arabe)
    Code Page : 1257  (ANSI - baltique)
    Code Page : 1258  (ANSI/OEM - Vietnam)
    Code Page : 1361  (coréen - Johab)
    Code Page : 20000 (CNS - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20001 (TCA - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20002 (Eten - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20003 (IBM5550 - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20004 (TeleText - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20005 (Wang - Taïwan)
    Code Page : 20105 (IA5 IRV alphabet international No.5)
    Code Page : 20106 (IA5 allemand)
    Code Page : 20107 (IA5 suédois)
    Code Page : 20108 (IA5 norvégien)
    Code Page : 20127 (ASCII - É-U.)
    Code Page : 20261 (T.61)
    Code Page : 20269 (ISO 6937 accent sans espace)
    Code Page : 20273 (IBM EBCDIC - Allemagne)
    Code Page : 20277 (IBM EBCDIC - Danemark/Norvège)
    Code Page : 20278 (IBM EBCDIC - Finlande/Suède)
    Code Page : 20280 (IBM EBCDIC - Italie)
    Code Page : 20284 (IBM EBCDIC - Amérique latine/Espagne)
    Code Page : 20285 (IBM EBCDIC - Royaume Uni)
    Code Page : 20290 (IBM EBCDIC - japonais Katakana étendu)
    Code Page : 20297 (IBM EBCDIC - France)
    Code Page : 20420 (IBM EBCDIC - arabe)
    Code Page : 20423 (IBM EBCDIC - grec)
    Code Page : 20424 (IBM EBCDIC - hébreu)
    Code Page : 20833 (IBM EBCDIC - coréen étendu)
    Code Page : 20838 (IBM EBCDIC - thaï)
    Code Page : 20866 (russe - KOI8)
    Code Page : 20871 (IBM EBCDIC - islandais)
    Code Page : 20880 (IBM EBCDIC - cyrillique (russe))
    Code Page : 20905 (IBM EBCDIC - turc)
    Code Page : 20924 (IBM EBCDIC - Latin-1/Système ouvert (1047 + Euro))
    Code Page : 20932 (JIS X 0208-1990  0212-1990)
    Code Page : 20936 (chinois simplifié GB2312)
    Code Page : 21025 (IBM EBCDIC - cyrillique (serbe, bulgare))
    Code Page : 21027 (minuscules alpha étendues)
    Code Page : 21866 (ukrainien - KOI8-U)
    Code Page : 28591 (ISO 8859-1 latin I)
    Code Page : 28592 (ISO 8859-2 Europe centrale)
    Code Page : 28593 (ISO 8859-3 latin 3)
    Code Page : 28594 (ISO 8859-4 baltique)
    Code Page : 28595 (ISO 8859-5 cyrillique)
    Code Page : 28596 (ISO 8859-6 arabe)
    Code Page : 28597 (ISO 8859-7 grec)
    Code Page : 28598 (ISO 8859-8 hébreu : ordre visuel)
    Code Page : 28599 (ISO 8859-9 latin 5)
    Code Page : 28603 (ISO 8859-13 Latin 7)
    Code Page : 28605 (ISO 8859-15 latin 9)
    Code Page : 37    (IBM EBCDIC - États-Unis/Canada)
    Code Page : 38598 (ISO 8859-8 hébreu : tri logique)
    Code Page : 437   (OEM - États-Unis)
    Code Page : 500   (IBM EBCDIC - international)
    Code Page : 50220 (ISO-2022 japonais sans Katakana demi largeur)
    Code Page : 50220 (ISO-2022 japonais avec Katakana demi largeur)
    Code Page : 50222 (ISO-2022 japonais JIS X 0201-1989)
    Code Page : 50225 (ISO-2022 coréen)
    Code Page : 50227 (ISO-2022 chinois simplifié)
    Code Page : 50229 (ISO-2022 chinois traditionnel)
    Code Page : 51949 (EUC-coréen)
    Code Page : 52936 (HZ-GB2312 chinois simplifié)
    Code Page : 54936 (chinois simplifié GB 18030)
    Code Page : 55000 (7 bits SMS GSM)
    Code Page : 55001 (espagnol 7 bits SMS GSM)
    Code Page : 55002 (portugais 7 bits SMS GSM)
    Code Page : 55003 (turc 7 bits SMS GSM)
    Code Page : 55004 (grec 7 bits SMS GSM)
    Code Page : 57002 (ISCII - dévanâgari)
    Code Page : 57003 (ISCII - bengali)
    Code Page : 57004 (ISCII - tamoul)
    Code Page : 57005 (ISCII - télougou)
    Code Page : 57006 (ISCII - assamais)
    Code Page : 57007 (ISCII - odia (oriya))
    Code Page : 57008 (ISCII - kannada)
    Code Page : 57009 (ISCII - malayalam)
    Code Page : 57010 (ISCII - gujarati)
    Code Page : 57011 (ISCII - pendjabi (gurmukhi))
    Code Page : 708   (arabe - ASMO)
    Code Page : 720   (arabe - ASMO transparent)
    Code Page : 737   (OEM - grec 437G)
    Code Page : 775   (OEM - baltique)
    Code Page : 850   (OEM - latin multilingue I)
    Code Page : 852   (OEM - latin II)
    Code Page : 855   (OEM - cyrillique)
    Code Page : 857   (OEM - turc)
    Code Page : 858   (OEM - latin multilingue I + Euro)
    Code Page : 860   (OEM - portugais)
    Code Page : 861   (OEM - islandais)
    Code Page : 862   (OEM - hébreu)
    Code Page : 863   (OEM - canadien français)
    Code Page : 864   (OEM - arabe)
    Code Page : 865   (OEM - nordique)
    Code Page : 866   (OEM - russe)
    Code Page : 869   (OEM - grec moderne)
    Code Page : 870   (IBM EBCDIC - multilingue/ROECE (latin-2))
    Code Page : 874   (ANSI/OEM - thaï)
    Code Page : 875   (IBM EBCDIC - grec moderne)
    Code Page : 932   (ANSI/OEM - japonais décalage JIS)
    Code Page : 936   (ANSI/OEM - chinois simplifié GBK)
    Code Page : 949   (ANSI/OEM - coréen)
    Code Page : 950   (ANSI/OEM - chinois traditionnel Big5)
    Code Page : 65000 (UTF-7)
    Code Page : 65001 (UTF-8)
```